# Design patterns used in symfony2

Tags: design-patterns, symfony, doctrine-orm

In *symfony2*, the *services* using Singleton patterns. Doctrine uses Unit of work patterns. I wonder a lot of design patterns may be used in *symfony2*. I think it will be useful to have better understanding of design patterns. My question is *what are the design patterns used in symfony2?*

Comment: Singletons? I don't think Symfony2 has any singletons...

Comment: Yes indeed, having a better understanding of design patterns will be useful. Like @WouterJ said, there probably aren't any singletons at all. Here you can learn about the DI pattern in php, it's a slide created by Fabien: http://www.slideshare.net/fabpot/dependency-injection-with-php-53

Comment: You should also follow this [guide](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1), it will give you an idea of how Symfony2 was built.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I just created this graph. As a guideline for a course on Sf2.

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you very much

Answer (score 14):

I think you can find any design pattern exploring Symfony2 components. For example, Form component provide you with Factory, Facade, Composite, Builder, Flyweight pattern examples.

And don't forget about the main Dependency Injection pattern used in Symfony2